# What determines whether I can surf on a cloud or just bust through it?

Tags: ski-safari

In Ski Safari, there's at least one achievement that involves surfing on clouds. I'm trying to nail down the method for consistently surfing them and avoiding busting straight through them and dropping back down to the ground.

At first I thought I had to be on my skis or a penguin to cloud surf, and that the heavier yeti or snowmobile would crash right through. Then I managed to surf a cloud on a snowmobile, totally by accident. (I haven't been able to do it again.)

So: what's the method? Does it have more to do with the angle at which I hit the cloud, the "vehicle" I'm riding, whether or not I'm boosting, the speed I'm going... etc? What's the trick?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with Diablo 3. ;) I was so excited to see a non-ignored question that I had to try and answer it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have any specific measurements or screen shots, but it's seemingly all about the angle at which you hit the cloud that determines whether you will surf them or not. You are right that you can surf cloulds with any animal (other than the eagle) or equipment. You can surf a cloud starting at the beginning of the cloud, the middle, or at the end, as long as you hit it at the right angle. You can also surf a cloud if you hit it in mid flip on your back; the game flips you right side up, so this could be a bug.

Generally if you are going fast enough that you have a speed trail behind you, then you are moving at too high a velocity and also too steep of an angle that it will bust you through the cloud instead of surfing it.